# Android : Count markers in the map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markers

How to know how many markers I have on my map ?
On iOS it's simple : myMap.annotations.count.

How to do this on Android ? thanks

Comment: Before you add the marker in your map you can create a list where you can add the marker to that list and then you can just get the size of that list/

Comment: thx but I can't do that. Some markers are deleted automatically by a server, so the count will be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this with the stock Maps. There are two options:

1. Keep track of the marker count yourself as they are added in and simply use that count when it is required; or
2. Introduce a dependency to [Android Maps Extensions](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-maps-extensions), which adds a `getMarkers()` function to the `Map` object.